# creating nodes with networkx to represent a cluster of points contained in a list

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I'm trying to implement a mapper algorithm in python, at my current step I have a list of lists, where each element contains a cluster connected components. From here I would like to create a node for each of these clusters, however,since lists are no hashable functions code like this:

```
    for cluster in cluster_array:
        G.add_node(cluster)
```

does not work. My other thought was to create nodes for as many elements there are in the list, like so:

```
    for cluster in range(len(cluster_array)):
        G.add_node(cluster)
```

My problem is that if I use the latter function to create my nodes. How do I associate the node with its respective list of connected components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "associate the node with its connected components". If all you need is for the information to be stored with the node, you can use attributes.

```
import networkx as nx                                     

# define some clusters                                                                                
cluster_array = [                                                               
    ['a','b','c'],                                                              
    ['X', 'Y', 'Z']]                                                             

# construct graph, with arbitrary label for nodes and the cluster info 
# as an attribute. (Here, the attribute is called "members")
G = nx.Graph()                                                                  
for i, cluster in enumerate(cluster_array):                                     
    G.add_node(i, members=cluster)
```

you can access the attributes in various ways, e.g.:

```
print(G.nodes(data=True))
>>> [(0, {'members': ['a', 'b', 'c']}), (1, {'members': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']})] 

print(nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'members'))
>>> {0: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 1: ['X', 'Y', 'Z']}
```